Estimated transactions on coalesced memory accesses
I've queried the CUDA device (T1000 SM_75) and picked the values of some specific CUDA device attributes as follows. (Note: this question is a little bit lengthy ☺.)
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    cuInit(0); CUdevice dev; cuDeviceGet(&dev, 0);

    int val; cuDeviceGetAttribute(&val, CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT, dev);
    printf("SM count:                    %d\n", val);
    cuDeviceGetAttribute(&val, CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_L2_CACHE_SIZE, dev);
    printf("L2 cache size:               %dM bytes\n\n", val >> 20);

    cuDeviceGetAttribute(&val, CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_REGISTERS_PER_MULTIPROCESSOR, dev);
    printf("Max registers per SM:        %dK 32-bit\n", val >> 10);
    cuDeviceGetAttribute(&val, CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_SHARED_MEMORY_PER_MULTIPROCESSOR, dev);
    printf("Max shared memory per SM:    %dK bytes\n\n", val >> 10);


    size_t bytes; cuDeviceTotalMem(&bytes, dev);
    printf("Total memory:                %luG bytes\n", bytes / 1000000000);
    cuDeviceGetAttribute(&val, CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_GLOBAL_MEMORY_BUS_WIDTH, dev);
    printf("Global memory bus width:     %d-bit\n\n", val);
}

SM count:                    14
L2 cache size:               1M bytes

Max registers per SM:        64K 32-bit
Max shared memory per SM:    64K bytes

Total memory:                4G bytes
Global memory bus width:     128-bit

I've got serval related questions below,

Is the 1M L2 cache allocated across the 14 SMs?
Is the 64K registers allocated across the 14 SMs, or does it imply total registers 64K * 14?
Is the 64K shared memory allocated across the 14 SMs, or does it imply total shared memory 64K * 14?
Does the 128-bit global memory bus width apply to local memory too?

My GPU (T1000 SM75) has a memory bus of 128-bit width.
When we try to estimate transactions on coalesced memory accesses, the CUDA device attributes contains nothing on L1 and L2 cache line sizes. However, does the following quotes from a previous article on cache statistics stay true even now?

Loads from the caches are made via transactions of a fixed size. L1
transactions are 128 bytes, and L2 are 32 bytes.


Global memory accesses are routed either through L1 and L2, or only
L2, depending on the architecture and the type of instructions used.
Local memory is routed through L1 and L2 cache. Shared memory accesses
do not go through any cache.

Here are the next quotes from the CUDA programming guide on memory  access here and there,

Global memory resides in device memory and device memory is accessed
via 32-, 64-, or 128-byte memory transactions.


Global memory accesses are always cached in L2.

For caching example, when each of the 32 threads within a warp requires 4-byte memory access to perfectly aligned address space, the warp will coalesce 128-byte (32 * 4-byte) memory access. Hence, will the warp issue 1 time 128-byte global memory transaction and 4 times 32-byte L2 cache transactions sequentially? Does a 128-byte (128 * 8-bit) global memory transaction require 8 consecutive physical accesses to the memory bus of 128-bit width?
Below are the last quotes from the CUDA programming guide on shared memory access here and there,

To achieve high bandwidth, shared memory is divided into equally-sized
memory modules, called banks, which can be accessed simultaneously.
Any memory read or write request made of n addresses that fall in n
distinct memory banks can therefore be serviced simultaneously,
yielding an overall bandwidth that is n times as high as the bandwidth
of a single module.


Shared memory has 32 banks that are organized such that successive
32-bit words map to successive banks. Each bank has a bandwidth of 32
bits per clock cycle.

Similarly for shared memory example, when each of the 32 threads within a warp requires 4-byte memory access to perfectly aligned address space, the warp will coalesce 128-byte (32 * 4-byte) memory access. Hence, will the warp issue 1 time 128-byte global memory transaction, and 4 times 32-byte L2 cache transactions and 1 time 128-byte (32 * 32-bit) shared memory transaction sequentially?

That's too many different questions for one SO post. You should really split this up to avoid it being closed. Also, some can be answered just by looking into the Compute Capabilities section of the Programming Guide. For example the number of 32bit registers is noted there as 64K per SM for all current CUDA versions.

Instead of rewriting all those queries you might want to start from the deviceQueryDrv sample.

Thanks for the suggestions, @Homer512! When I look at the docs, it says MAX number of registers/shared-memory per SM. To me, it's unclear if the MAX number of them is shared by all SMs or exclusive to 1 SM. I've thought all the sub-questions closely related, thus asked them in one., but it depends.

For a technical deep dive on these topics I can recommend Requests, Wavefronts, Sectors Metrics: Understanding and Optimizing Memory-Bound Kernels with Nsight Compute and How to Understand and Optimize Shared Memory Accesses using Nsight Compute (both need registration with Nvidia).

It does not say MAX number of registers. Table 21 row 14 clearly reads "Number of 32-bit registers per SM". You may also be interested in papers such as Zhe Jia, et.al: "Dissecting the NVidia Turing T4 GPU via Microbenchmarking"

@Homer512, yes! there's table 21 row 14 "number of registers per SM" additionally. But how about shared memory?

Thanks a lot for the technical report reference, @Homer512! Those benchmarks reveal more than what I'd conceive in great details, except that instruction pipeline seems non-disclosed. I'm not sure whether Nvidia GPUs have some sorts of support on it. I know this is one of definitive features on modern superscalar CPUs.

I also find the comments are intriguingly down to the point on this HN thread Demystifing GPU Compute Architectrue.


Is the 1M L2 cache allocated across the 14 SMs?

Yes, the L2 cache is a device-wide resource.  You can get an idea of this by looking at any of the architecture whitepapers, such as this one for turing/cc7.5 GPUs.

Is the 64K registers allocated across the 14 SMs, or does it imply total registers 64K * 14?

Each SM has 64K registers.  This can be found out in the whitepaper or by studying the architecture sections of the programming guide

Is the 64K shared memory allocated across the 14 SMs, or does it imply total shared memory 64K * 14?

Shared memory is also a per-sm resource.  The same resources mentioned previously will clarify this for you (architecture whitepaper, arch sections of the programming guide).  So the total is 64K times the number of SMs in that GPU, for that arch type (cc7.5).

Does the 128-bit global memory bus width apply to local memory too?

Local memory is a logical resource that can manifest (i.e. be physically backed) in registers, cache, or device memory.  When it manifests in device memory, the same memory bus is used to retrieve it as would be used to retrieve items in the logical global space.

Does the following quotes from a previous article on cache statistics stay true even now?

The L1 and L2 granularities since Pascal (cc6.0) are minimum of 32-bytes each.  The remaining statements there are basically correct.

Is it correct for this basic calculation to fulfill the requirement?

Yes, that is basically correct.  One possible efficient path for usage of memory is to have each thread in the warp load a 4-byte adjacent quantity.  Having that block of data be aligned to a 128-byte boundary may also be beneficial, but is often of less concern.  Unit 4 of this online training series will delve into all  the nuances here in more detail.

Does a 128-byte (128 * 8-bit) global memory transaction require 8 consecutive physical accesses to the memory bus of 128-bit width?

That's not the way to think about it.  You're using "global memory" here (which is a logical space definition) where I think you really mean "device memory".  The minimum access granularity from device memory on most GPUs is 32-bytes. These memory "segments" are "aligned" to the divisions implied by the L2 cache "sectors".  A single 32-byte segment in memory could be retrieved in a single operation, occupying whatever bus width may exist, at least up to 256 bits wide.  Multiple segments to be retrieved could occupy even wider memory bus widths, on GPUs that may have those.

Is this calculation correct, too?

Yes, generally speaking, shared memory efficiency will be highest using a similar pattern as what you would use for high efficiency from device memory.  However shared memory allows for more flexible access patterns (one 32-bit item per "bank") to achieve high efficiency, which goes beyond what is possible for highest efficiency access to device (off-chip DRAM) memory.  We don't use the words "coalesce" to describe shared memory activity, nor do we refer to caches w.r.t shared memory.  Efficient use of shared memory is a fairly involved topic, but is covered in numerous posts here on the cuda tag, and furthermore is covered in the same training unit I previously linked.

Thanks for your great answer, @Robert Crovella! You've drawn a clear line between logic space and physical space that I had forgotten to distinct.

Yes, what I've asked is whether a 128-byte global memory transaction to the logic space incurs 8 consecutive accesses to the physical device memory of 128-bit bus width on my GPU for caching warmup to saturate the physical cache memory. I'm thinking of the usual scenario on memory access path: host memory <-> device memory <-> L2 cache <-> shared memory <-> registers. The data transfer between the slow device memory and the fast L2 cache should be designated as few times as possible, but at least once for caching saturation.

Retrieving 128 bytes from device memory would require retrieval of at least four 32-byte segments from memory.  The precise way that gets done will depend on the memory bus configuration, but for coalesced/aligned retrieval it would never involve "8 consecutive accesses".  The unit of request/transaction to device memory is always in terms of 32-byte "contiguous" blocks, not bits or any other granularity/arrangement.  Again, the exact "alignment" of these blocks (that I refer to as "segments") is aligned to L2 cache sector partitioning.  A L2 cache sector holds a segment, no more, no less.

In other words,  if perfectly aligned, a 128-byte retrieval from device memory is mapped to four 32-byte (logical) segments (physically contiguous memory) as your comment has reiterated, right? If memory bus is configured 128-bit width, is a retrieval from memory mapped to a half 32-byte segment? If it is and perfectly aligned,  will four 32-byte segments incur 8 times retrievals from memory to fill four 32-byte L2 cache sectors? I'm still uncertain having understood this.

The exact mapping of retrieved bytes to bits or lanes in memory is unspecified, and I can't imagine why it should matter for a CUDA programmer.  It should be sufficient to know that the retrieval of the 32-byte segment will be as efficient as the CUDA programmer can make it, according to your description.

Ideally, a CUDA programmer only talks to the API, which hides the HW and the implementation details away. Since the prime factors for me to use GPU than CPU for computing are cost-effectively lower latency and higher throughput (and comparably much better performance benchmarks ☺) , sometimes I can hardly resist to explore more details underneath. Understandably, the journey for such exploration could distract the programmer from attention on the programing model CUDA designers prescribe and the real beneficiary that it brings to us.
